# caffe memory required how to calculate?

Tags: deep-learning, caffe

When you want to train a net you will get a log information like:

```
Memory required for data: 493376512
```

How do you interpret the number? Is it in bytes, bits?

Comment: In case you haven't extracted the info from those answers, the size is given in bytes.

Comment: Ok thank you! Yeah these answers say literally that it is not possible to compute it right? @Prune

Comment: I'll summarize in an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your direct question, the memory usage for the layer is given in bytes, not bits.

Overall, the memory reported is all of the layer's required memory that can be computed at initialization.  The parameter and buffer space is allocated as needed, so it's not useful to report those in an aggregate sum -- some of them might take less total memory due to serialized re-use.

As the one answer says, the most effective way to determine the max memory usage is to run a forward pass and grab its high-water mark.

Comment: Ok thanks :) I assume you would run the forward pass with c++ rather than python?

Comment: Either should do.  I rarely run through a language interface; rather, I directly invoke **./build/tools/caffe**.

Comment: Hm I always run through the python interface because I havent seen any tutorial which showed how to use the c++ code. How do you setup your data then? Somehow you have to create a lmdb or hdf5 file? @Prune

Comment: Yeah btw. I am doing the same. I always run: ..caffe train -solver... @Prune

Comment: Right.  I did the LMDB conversion so long ago, I don't recall the command.  I just specify that path in the "path" attribute of the train and test layers.  However, that's a separate processing step, not part of the run.  Then I use the "native" (supplied) LMDB-format input layer.

Comment: Oh ok, thats pretty basic and does not work for me :). But thanks anyway! @Prune

Answer (score 0):

See shelhamer's comment:
https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/2387#issuecomment-97910200

> It's the memory required for all the top blobs or "data" in the sense
>   of layer outputs. It excludes the diffs, the parameters, and any
>   intermediate blobs within layers. @jeffdonahue do you remember the
>   motivation for this number?

And longjon:

> Since layers are individually responsible for allocating parameters
>   and buffers, there's no way in general to know the total amount of
>   memory required except by running a forward pass.